# How to test if Osmosis is installed on openSuse?

Tags: linux, osmosis

update; thanks to the answer i have done some more

i teste like you recomended;

```
linux-wyee:/home/martin/gis/test/test2/a_repo # :~> cnf osmosis
linux-wyee:/home/martin/gis/test/test2/a_repo # cnf osmosis

Das Programm 'osmosis' was found here:
  * osmosis [ Pfad: /usr/bin/osmosis, Repository: zypp (gis_-_osmosis) ]

Try installing with:
    zypper install osmosis
```

well just wondering - does this mean i have to install it!!?

love to hear from your

**btw-** do i need postgis and - yes i guess i have to install postgresql too.
**Note;** i have a apache / lamp allready up and running on my opensuse 12.1.

I am pretty new to GiS and to Linux. I try to install Osmosis on my openSuse 12.1 System.

Here what i have in YAST:

```
linux-wyee:/home/martin # zypper lr -d
#  | Alias                                       | Name                                        | Aktiviert | Aktualisieren | Priorität | Typ    | URI                                                                                   | Dienst
---+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------
 1 | Aktualisierungen-für-openSUSE-12.1-12.1-1.4 | Aktualisierungen für openSUSE 12.1 12.1-1.4 | Ja        | Ja            |   99      | rpm-md | http://download.opensuse.org/update/12.1/                                             |       
 2 | UpdatedApps                                 | KDE UpdatedApps Repo                        | Ja        | Ja            |   99      | rpm-md | http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/KDE:/UpdatedApps/openSUSE_12.1/             |       
 3 | gis_-_osmosis                               | gis - osmosis                               | Ja        | Ja            |   99      | rpm-md | http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Application:/Geo/openSUSE_12.1/             |       
 4 | openSUSE-12.1-12.1-1.4                      | openSUSE-12.1-12.1-1.4                      | Ja        | Nein          |   99      | yast2  | cd:///?devices=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-TSSTcorp_CDDVDW_SN-S083C_m1L3456789KLMNOP,/dev/sr0 |       
 5 | packman-x86_64                              | packman-x86_64                              | Ja        | Nein          |   99      | rpm-md | http://packman.inode.at/suse/12.1/                                                    |       
 6 | repo-debug                                  | openSUSE-12.1-Debug                         | Nein      | Ja            |   99      | NONE   | http://download.opensuse.org/debug/distribution/12.1/repo/oss/                        |       
 7 | repo-debug-update                           | openSUSE-12.1-Update-Debug                  | Nein      | Ja            |   99      | NONE   | http://download.opensuse.org/debug/update/12.1/                                       |       
 8 | repo-non-oss                                | openSUSE-12.1-Non-Oss                       | Ja        | Ja            |   99      | yast2  | http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/12.1/repo/non-oss/                          |       
 9 | repo-oss                                    | openSUSE-12.1-Oss                           | Ja        | Ja            |   99      | yast2  | http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/12.1/repo/oss/                              |       
10 | repo-source                                 | openSUSE-12.1-Source                        | Nein      | Ja            |   99      | NONE   | http://download.opensuse.org/source/distribution/12.1/repo/oss/                       |       
linux-wyee:/home/martin #
```

Regarding the above mentioned listing of repos - can we say that I have osmosis installed yet?

How can i test if osmosis is installed?

Can this be tested on commandline - in terminal? How?

Answer (score 2):

to do so you just have to type in console "cnf osmosis":

```
:~> cnf osmosis
```

Then you will receive the message whether it is installed and the path to the programme (if installed) or the repo with it  (if you have repo with this software). Here is my output for example:

```
The program 'osmosis' can be found in the following package:
  * osmosis [ path: /usr/bin/osmosis, repository: zypp (Application:Geo) ]

Try installing with:
    sudo zypper install osmosis
```

You can find osmosis in "Application:Geo" repository for openSUSE:

> http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Application:/Geo/openSUSE_12.1/

UPD: you've installed this repo already and called it gis_osmisis. so you will need to install osmosis itself. Note that there is a GUI for package management: go to computer->install/remove software in application luncher, or Software Manager in Yast. Note that in openSUSE you don't need to use console for the most of administration tasks - there is a very user-friendly Yast.

Comment: i teste like you recomended; **see above!!**



linux-wyee:/home/martin/gis/test/test2/a_repo # :~> cnf osmosis
linux-wyee:/home/martin/gis/test/test2/a_repo # cnf osmosis
                    
Das Programm 'osmosis' was found here:
  * osmosis [ Pfad: /usr/bin/osmosis, Repository: zypp (gis_-_osmosis) ]

Try installing with:
    zypper install osmosis


well just wondering - does this mean i have to install it!!?

love to hear from your

btw- do i need postgis and - yes i guess i have to install postgresql too.
Note; i have a apache / lamp allready up and running on my opensuse 12.1.

Comment: @zero, yes, it seems that you have to install it, the command is already given: "sodo zypper install osmosis". If you are planing to use POstGIS, then you need to install it too. Hope this helps, I won't be available for several days.